# CVS to GIT migration - Not all the files and directories got migrated to git

Tags: git, cvs

I did a cvs repo migration to GIT using cvs2git. After migration i notice that not all directories and files got moved to GIT. When i looked into the subdirectories which didnt move to GIT, i noticed that all those files are with r r r permission. is this an issue? On the root there exist a file say a.java and it has r r r permission, which got migrated to git with rw- r-- r-- . Looks very strange. Unable to identify which is causing issue. Migration didnt throw any error even though.
Help is much appreciated

Comment: git does not track file permissions other than the executable bit.

Answer (score 1):

cvs2git, of course, migrates all files from the CVS repository.  Of course, not all files might exist on the master branch, for example because they were deleted in CVS sometime in history or they only ever existed on another branch/tag.

But instead of trying to misuse stack overflow to get help on your own particular support problem, why don't you report your problem [with a sufficient amount of information](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/faq.html#gettinghelp) to the cvs2svn mailing list?